# Displaying a <div> content when loading a page, appears when refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not able to solve this issue, I'm not a professional javascript coder.

I have several buttons displaying a `div` content. When the page loads, the first `div` must be visible, but hidden when clicking other buttons. I could make this with a script and works fine.

The problem is when the content showed is different than the first `div` and the page is refreshed, the first div becomes visible. I know is the logic behavior based on this script, what should I change to show the first `div` when loading and not when refreshing the page?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#apa, #com, #adi").click(function() {
    if ($('.cover').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('.cover').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
  $("#apa").click(function() {
    if ($('.cover').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('.cover').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  display: none;
}

.image:target {
  display: block;
}

.cover {
  display: block;
}

div {display:flex; margin: 0 12px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image01" class="image cover">
  <img src="https://www.african.cam.ac.uk/images/secondlevel/dasshills/image_preview">
</div>

<div id="image02" class="image">
  <img src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/60436988/large.png">
</div>

<div id="image03" class="image">
  <img src="https://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/crop_8.jpg">
</div>

<div>
<div id="apa">
    <a href="#image01">Picture 1</a>
</div>
<div id="com">
    <a href="#image02">Picture 2</a>
</div>
<div id="adi">
    <a href="#image03">Picture 3</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: This could be achieved by either putting something on the url to specify which element(s) should be shown/hidden, or likewise store something in sessionStorage to do the same thing

Comment: You could use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload) to detect when a page is being refreshed and at that point associate the open element with a URL parameter or store it in local/sessionstorage as @Taplar suggests above.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `a` is interactive, you can not have interactive content in a `button` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button